# Update an old Nutch plugin to be able to use Xpath parsing in Nutch 2.3.1

Tags: java, solr, nutch

I am working on a project with apache Nutch 2.3.1 and I need to be able to extract specific data from the downloaded html pages. I found a plugin (parse-xml NUTCH-185) that would help me for this purpose but some of the libraries it uses no longer exist or is deprecated, what I intend to do is make necessary changes to make it compatible with Nutch 2.3.1
The libraries that give me an error in the Nutch compilation are these, could you help me find the equivalents for Nutch 2.3.1?

```
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.nutch.crawl.CrawlDatum;
import org.apache.nutch.crawl.Inlinks;
import org.apache.nutch.parse.ParseData;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nutch 2.3.1 is not *the next version* of Nutch 1.x. Nutch has at any given time 2 major "branches": Nutch 1.x/master/trunk and Nutch 2.x. Nutch 2.x is very different to its brother. They share lots of design ideas, but with different implementations. In short, you cannot find those classes because they don't exist in Nutch 2.x.

> The `org.apache.lucene.*` are not implemented in Nutch, but used directly from the Apache Lucene library.

Nutch 2.x has a very different architecture compared to Nutch 1.x. This means that the update for that plugin is not only about replacing those imports. You'll need to adapt the code to the new architecture. Although the main logic of the plugin should be roughly the same.